# Foundation Slider does not update input

Tags: zurb-foundation, pug

On [this page](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/range_slider.html#with-input) there is a slider updating a input box with example HTML code.  You can also see that same code in the source.

I would like to use this in my application so I transplanted it into my code and converted it to Jade (aka Pug).  The source now looks like:

```
    div.row
        div.small-10.columns
            div.range-slider(data-slider data-options="display_selector: #days-off-count; initial: 28;")
                span.range-slider-handle(role="slider" tabindex="0")
                span.range-slider-active-segment
        div.small-2.columns
            input(type="number" id="days-off-count" value="28")
```

And the resulting html looks like this (after prettifying it):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-10 columns">
    <div data-slider data-options="display_selector: #days-off-count; initial: 28;" class="range-slider">
      <span role="slider" tabindex="0" class="range-slider-handle"></span>
      <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 columns">
    <input type="number" id="days-off-count" value="28">
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is very close that shown on in the docs.  **However on the resulting page the input box is not updated.**  If I change the input box to a span like in the
['With Label'](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/range_slider.html#with-label) example it updates.

```
span(id="days-off-count" value="28")
```

becomes

```
<span id="days-off-count" value="28"></span>
```

I have the `foundation.js` and the `.slider.js` included at the bottom of the page.

In addition, if I manually change the value of the input box via the keyboard the slider will jump to that position, so there is some sort of link there.

The software being used:

- Ubuntu 14_04
- Chrome
- Node v0.10.25
- Express 4.14.0
- Jade 1.11.0
- Foundation v5.5.0

Other things to note:

- The page has more than one slider so any javascript solutions need to take this into account.

Comment: I think you need data binding http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#data-binding: `aria-controls="days-off-count"`

Comment: I am using v5 and the v5 demo works. I am trying to figure out why it doesn't work on my jade based site.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in v5.5.0 (not working JSfiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/jth99pkw/3/) but fixed by v5.5.3 (working JSfiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/tw1we8fk/3/) can you update your foundation version or do you need a fix for this specific version?

Comment: Hmm. I see what you mean. I will discuss it with the powers-that-be and see what their view is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug ([hasOwnProperty instead of hasAttribute #6221](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/6221)) in the version of Foundation (5.5.0) you're using. It seems that while it initially applied only to Firefox, it now applies to Chrome too.

Example with (broken) sliders from 5.5.0: [jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/jth99pkw/3](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/jth99pkw/3/)

Example with (working) sliders from 5.5.3: [jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/tw1we8fk/3](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/tw1we8fk/3/)

The bug was fixed here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/commit/896e81f1275eefbbdb84ce4da9004ab059b26d45

Basically, go to `foundation.slider.js` and change this (line 157):

```
if (settings.display_selector != '') {
    $(settings.display_selector).each(function(){
        if (this.hasOwnProperty('value')) { // this is the mistake / bug
            $(this).val(value);
        } else {
            $(this).text(value);
        }
    });
}
```

to this:

```
if (settings.display_selector != '') {
    $(settings.display_selector).each(function(){
        if (this.hasAttribute('value')) { // this should fix it
            $(this).val(value);
        } else {
            $(this).text(value);
        }
    });
}
```

This is not my fix, it's the same as the patch, but it should mean that when you do upgrade you don't need to modify your application code to account for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe I be wrong... but you didn't specify the version, you give an example from Foundation v5... are you not have installed Foundation v6?

Try this example : https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html

2) After you include your js files, you need to have this:

```
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
```

Edit: Sorry, first time I didn't read all, maybe the problem is that the Foundation use the "value" attribute, which is an attribute designed for `<input>` tags: 
value   `<button>, <input>, <li>, <option>, <meter>, <progress>, <param>`   Specifies the value of the element

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp

Comment: 1) The site I am updating is using v5. 2) It does have this - as I put in my post it works when using the span method but not the input. Edit) It works on the Foundation docs site, so why doesn't it work on mine.

Comment: You put "value" atribute on the span... on the docs "span" tag has only ID attribute, remove it and try again :) Ex( you have '<span id="days-off-count" value="28"></span>', on the foundation page the span has only the id: '<span id="sliderOutput3"></span>' )

Comment: The `span` works.  It is the `input` that doesn't work.